# Attempting to input a nvarchar parameter to execute a stored proc. Getting a VBA Error: Run Time Error '3708' Parameter Object is Improperly defined

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a VBA project, the data is pulled from a sql database.  The query works a different stored proc that only deals with numbers.  I changed val to a variant and it correctly pulls the value of F2.  When I try to generate the output, the error occurs.  Any help would be appreciated.

Changed up a few types such as adParamInput, but nothing has worked that well.

```
Sub SQLDatabase_StoredProc1()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlCommand As ADODB.Command, prm As Object
Dim colOffset As Integer
colOffset = 1
Dim qf As Object, numOfRecordsAffected As Long

Dim val As Variant
val = Range("F2").Value
'Dim val As String
'val = Range("F2").Value

Sheets("database").Select
Cells.Range("A1:D100").ClearContents

Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
cnSQL.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Integrated Security = sspi; Initial Catalog = [database]; Data Source = [server]"


Set sqlCommand = New ADODB.Command
sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = cnSQL
sqlCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
sqlCommand.CommandText = "OwnershipTestProc"
Set prm = sqlCommand.CreateParameter("ID", adVarChar, adParamInput)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Append prm
sqlCommand.Parameters("ID") = val


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open sqlCommand

If rs.EOF Then
MsgBox ("There is no data for the Tax ID. rs.eof = " & rs.EOF)
Else
MsgBox ("# of records = " & rs.RecordCount)
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs
For Each qf In rs.Fields
    Range("A1").Offset(0, colOffset).Value = qf.name
    colOffset = colOffset + 1
Next qf
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The goal is for the stored proc to be executed and output data.  The parameter passed in ("ID") should not be limited to just numbers.

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the size for a string (`adVarChar`) parameter.

```
Set prm = sqlCommand.CreateParameter("ID", adVarChar, adParamInput)
prm.Value = val
prm.Size = len(val)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Append prm
```

or, shorter

```
Set prm = sqlCommand.CreateParameter("ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(val), val)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Append prm
```

Comment: Just be careful, as far as I remember you need to set len at least to 1, so the code will fail if you pass an empty string.